# How can I make the WooCommerce "Add to cart" button switch to a quantity increment button when clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, woocommerce, product-quantity

I would to like modify the WooCommerce "Add to cart" button behavior as follows:

1. When the "Add to cart" button is clicked, the selected item is added to the cart and the button changes to a quantity increment selector with plus/minus buttons. (There should be no "View cart" button, either.)
2. The quantity in the cart can then be increased or decreased by clicking the plus/minus buttons on the quantity selector.
3. If the quantity is reduced down to zero, the quantity increment button reverts backs to the "Add to cart" button.

All these actions should take place without reloading the page. I would ideally like to apply this to all areas of the shop (shop archive pages, product pages, quick view modal windows, cart), however if this is not possible then just on the shop page is fine.

I have tried to use [Themes.Zone's WooCommerce Ajax Quantity](https://wordpress.org/plugins/themeszone-woocommerce-ajax-quantity/) plugin, but cannot seem to get it to work on my site... shame, because it's exactly what I'm looking for!

Please refer to the resources below for examples of the ideal finished product:

[Click here for screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGr5R.png)

[Click here to see a working example on The Happy Apple's website](https://happyappleseddon.myfoodworks.com.au/category/fruit)

[Click here to see a working example on Woolworths' website](https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/browse/fruit-veg/fruit)

Any help would be much appreciated! I am super new to the web dev game so writing the code myself is totally unrealistic!! >D< Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am on the same mission as you, please tell me you found an answer? As regards Themes.Zone's WooCommerce Ajax Quantity plugin; there seems to be a Jquery issue causing it to not work correctly ThemesZones-WooCommerce-Ajax-Quantity-plugin/public/js/tz-wc-ajax-qty-public.js?ver=1.2.0 line 10; the .live() function is now deprecated and needs to be replaced with .on(), however I tried to do that and pushed the change to the server, then when i loaded my Wordpress site again and opened inspector I could see that the Jquery migration helper had converted to back to .live? which isn't working on WP